# How to transfer cpu load to RAM?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using my own PHP script with MySQL and when there are many users on the site I can see that CPU Load is somewhat high and RAM usage is low. For example, CPU Usage is about 45% and used RAM is 3GB out of 64GB.

How can I make it so it would use more RAM and less CPU? I'm using MyISAM as MySQL engine, php 7.0. I don't need an answer that explains step by step on how to do this, but I would appreciate any directions because I don't know how to get on with it.

I have a dedicated server using cPanel, WHM, Apache and I have full control over what is on the server.

Comment: CPU and RAM aren't things you can "transfer between"- they serve very different purposes.  Try reading up on how CPU and Memory are used by databases, and I think you will realize your questions doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: MyISAM is probably not a good start. When it updates a row etc, it locks the entire table. Depending on database design, with joins etc, that could cause a bottleneck and cause CPU increases as it's controlling a queue. Try InnoDB (Row level locking) for starters. PHP 7.1 is far better, performance wise, then 7.0, so I'd upgrade that too.

You also didn't state what CPU you have, but with 64GB of RAM, I'd expect a decent one to match.

Comment: @Derek: there probably are algorithms that can be tuned to prefer RAM or CPU usage (e.g. if there are two ways to solve the same problem, one is fast at the expense of high RAM usage, another is slower but reduces RAM etc). One could surmise that changing the way a SQL engine optimiser tackles a database query _might_ have the effect the OP wants. 0r perhaps there are settings in `my.ini` that can be tuned to reduce processor usage. (FWIW I don't think the question is particularly answerable without example queries).

Comment: @halfer in any case, this discussion doesn't belong here.  Should be moved to DBA.

Comment: @Derek: I don't have strong views on that. MrMarlow suggests that PHP should be upgraded to 7.1 to reduce CPU usage, and if that possibility is to be considered, then DBA might not be a good fit. Possibly Server Fault? - but then I've gotten into trouble in the past for recommending that and not knowing their specific posting requirements!

Comment: @MrMarlow I've heard that MyISAM is better for SELECT queries. My site is SELECT query heavy, about 4 of SELECT queries per page load and I've got about 10 page loads every second (10 users every second). About PHP 7.1 - as soon it lands on whm I will try it

Comment: @DerekBrown mostly I'm asking about MySQL configuration as the site is very mysql heavy, advice on what engine should use etc. I will edit my question a bit.

Comment: @halfer yeah I'm asking about MySQL config advice too. As I said in the comment above, most of queries are "SELECT"s and one UPDATE query that is for a specific row only, I have only a few insert queries. I've heard MyISAM is better for select heavy database, but I'm not sure as script takes some chunk of the CPU. I just want to make use of my RAM.

Comment: @buli: would you be able to add your slowest query into the question? That will give us a concrete [mcve] to consider. If you can add rough numbers of rows per table involved, and an explain plan, someone should be able to give you some tuning tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to use RAM to relieve CPU load is **caching**.

That is, if your app needs some data results that are pretty computationally expensive to produce, you should pre-compute them and store them in RAM, then the next time your app needs those results, they can be fetched from the cache, probably a lot more cheaply than recomputing them.

Popular tools for this is Memcached or Redis.